# Forms angular 2

Tags: angular

Tenho uma tela chamada login na mesma tela tenho dois forms um com usuario e senha e outro apenas com campo email. No primeiro form eu tenho esse trecho de código:

```
<a href="#" class=""> clique aqui
```

quando eu clicar: clique aqui, eu quero abrir segundo form na mesma tela, ou seja, primeiro form desaparece e entra segundo form. Como faço ? já tentei com jquery não deu certo. Estou utilizando angular 2.

Comment: Poste o seu código completo para que possamos te ajudar. Está muito vago sua dúvida, dê mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através do ngIf

```
 <button (click)="form2 = !form2">Mudar</button>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" *ngIf="form2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="form2 Email" *ngIf="!form2">
```

Ou através do hidden

```
  <button (click)="form2 = !form2">Mudar</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email" [hidden]="form2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="form2 Email" [hidden]="!form2">
```